# Error in Calling Matlab Engine from Fortran program written in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: matlab, hyperlink, fortran, call

I am getting the following error while trying to call Matlab engine using a Fortran program from Visual Studio 2015.

--fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libeng.lib'--

I did the following steps but still got the same error:

1). Changed the Active Solution Platfrom to x64 (since my matlab is  64 bit).

2). Included the following paths in their corresponding fields in Property Pages --> Configuration Properties:
    a). Configuration Properties --> Fortran --> Additional Include Directories : 'C:\Program 
        Files\MATLAB\R2019a\extern\include'
    b). Configuration Properties --> Linker --> General -->  Additional Library Directories :'C:\Program 
        Files\MATLAB\R2019a\extern\lib\win64\microsoft'
    c). Configuration Properties --> Linker --> Input --> Additional Dependencies :libeng.lib

3). Added the path 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\bin\win64' in system variables.

My version of Matlab is R2019a and Visual Studio is 2015 with Intel Parallel Studio XE 2018.

Please help me sort this out.

Comment: First, have you confirmed that the directory you added in b) actually contains a `libeng.lib`? Copy the text from the property and paste into the "address bar" of a Windows Explorer window. Please show us the Link command from the buildlog.htm in the Debug or Release folder you used. (Do keep in mind that when you update project properties that by default they go in one configuration only.)

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for responding. I did the check and found 'libeng.lib' present in that directory. I have pasted the text I found in my buildlog.htm file below:

Comment: Link /OUT:"x64\Debug\trial_01.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\bin\win64'" /LIBPATH:"'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\extern\lib\win64\microsoft'" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"x64\Debug\trial_01.exe.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"H:\Softwares\Fortran\VisualStudio\trial_01\trial_01\x64\Debug\trial_01.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE/IMPLIB:"H:\Softwares\Fortran\VisualStudio\trial_01\trial_01\x64\Debug\trial_01.lib" libeng.lib -qm64 "x64\Debug\trial_01.obj"

Comment: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libeng.lib'

Comment: *I don't know what to make out of this. Kindly provide your comments.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I have been on vacation all month. I suggest you take this to the Intel Fortran forum at https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler as we need more info than is convenient to include here, and there will be more eyes on it. Include a link to this discussion. I would ask for proof that libeng.lib exists in one of the MATLAB folders you named.

Comment: Thank you Steve. I tried using compiler directive commands and the compiler successfully fetched the libraries.